# Meaning of predicate logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

As far as I know, the only difference between predicate logic and propositional logic is the usage of quantifiers and expressing propositions in the way which we use predicates.

Also, we know that we can use rules of propositional logic instead of quantifiers; for example we can say $P(x_1)\wedge P(x_2) \wedge ...\wedge P(x_n)$ instead of $\forall x P(x)$, when we know that $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are all of the elements of the domain. But obviously it is more convenient to use $\forall x P(x)$.

So, can we say that predicate logic is nothing more than propositional logic with some notations which bring us easiness to work with?

Comment: Those extra notations make a big difference.   Propositional logic is decidable.  Predicate logic is not.

Comment: @hardmath OMG. Thank you for your response. I do not know anything about decidability.

Comment: "for example we can say P(x1)∧P(x2)∧...∧P(xn) instead of ∀xP(x)" NO; we cannot "unwind" with conjunction the formula $\forall n (n \ge 0)$

Comment: If by 'predicate logic' we mean 'first-order logic', first-order logic also has rules (and/or axioms) for manipulating quantifiers which propositional logic doesn't have.  Predicate logic also having predicates can capture the meaning of more of statements made in natural language than propositional logic can.

Comment: A theory is *decidable* iff there is a deterministic algorithm that, given a statement, outputs whether or not it is a *theorem* of that theory.